# What's with the abandoned train near Valentine?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

So, I just left camp, and there's a train abandoned on the track right outside of the forest. It has two passenger cars, a mail car, and a caboose. There is nothing in the train except a few bits of trash. All the containers are left open as though it was recently robbed, and I can't figure out what happened. I'm afraid to try and drive it, because I feel like it's a trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just hopped in to drive an abandoned train....I think it's just been robbed while you're nearby and everyone ran afterwards.

Comment: When I came across this train, I had to mop up a few O'Driscolls.  I assume it was them who had robbed the train, but they didn't have any nice loot on them.  I didn't see any need to drive the train since you don't get anything for driving trains (at least that I could see).

Comment: Well, I drive the trains when I can because it's a fast way to get from, say, valentine to granite pass

Answer (score -1):

Been playing since the game first come out and I just now found an abandoned train outside of Saint Denis that I've never seen before. It's completely working but it's only got one passenger car, a caboose, and a storage car. The storage car has a lockbox that you can open but it's empty except for a single 25 cent coin. There is a bunch of boxes and crates with empty old US mail style bags that say coins on it. You can take the train nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, this was mainly the same information already in the question. Do you have an answer as to how this train fits in the story or if there are any quests related to it? This would be the kind of answer that readers would probably find more helpful.